# Smelly water in between washer barrels

Tags: clothes-washer

My washer has water in between the 2 barrels after each load. The water leaves a terrible smell, what is causing this and how can I fix it. The washer is a "Amana" top load washer

Answer (score 1):

Possible problems include:

- pump bad (may be eating a sock or something)
- control board bad
- drain line has an issue
- possibly a transmission issue if the spin isn't working

All, or virtually all, the water should pump out. In the short term, put in a cup of bleach and run a short cold cycle (no clothes or soap) to kill off the smellies.

I had a similar issue at one point and was pretty sure the pump was bad, but I wanted to remove it before ordering a replacement - when I did, I found an obstruction (in my case, some silicone rubber from a prior tub repair job, which I had done "inside and out" to "make sure" - the inside part peeled off, the outside part continued to work) lodged in the impeller. Removed the obstruction, reinstalled the pump, washer worked fine again. Unless it **is** eating an escaped sock, you probably won't get that lucky.

Answer (score 1):

How much water are we talking about? I can't imagine more than half an inch or so at the bottom of the actual tub, inside which the perforated basket looks dry unless you really slosh the tub around on its mounts.

It's actually next to impossible for a traditional washing machine to evacuate every drop of water from the system. The drain pump, activated by an electronically-controlled clutch using power from the main motor, has to force the draining water up the drain hose to the elevated drain (the washer itself doesn't have any sort of drain plug to keep the water in the tub, so this elevated drain keeps the tub full until the pump forcibly removes the water) and not all of it will make it all the way.

First off, it helps if the drain hose is as short as possible. A lot of newer washers will come with a long hose designed to be fed down the drain, which reduces the chance of leaks over the older style of a rubber elbow clamped to the end of a shorter drain hose, but I find the longer hose tends to want to work its way back out of the drain.